# Binance Api [buy limit] it says that I have no funds to make the purchase but in fact there are

Tags: api, binance

Hi everyone I'm trying to use Binace's bees and so far everything has been fine, I have already made some purchases and sells using the market order mode, all perfect, now I'm trying to place a Limit order.

but I always get the same answer.

> "{"code":-2010,"msg":"Account has insufficient balance for requested action."}"

My wallet consists of two test cryptocurrencies:

**BNB -> free 0.07100 | Locked 0**

**USDT -> free 50.69828637 | Locked 0**

I'm trying to make the request like this:

`symbol=BNBUSDT&type=LIMIT&timeInForce=GTC&quantity=0.333&price=120.001&side=BUY&recvWindow=5000&timestamp=1616195182000`

*This is my main code and as you can see i set the parameters correctly, what can it be?*

```
$request = [
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldSymbol => 'BNBUSDT',
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldType => 'LIMIT',
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldTimeInForce => 'GTC',
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldQuantity => number_format( (30/120),3),
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldPrice => 120.001,
   BinanceEndpointApi::fieldSide => 'BUY'
];

$res = $binance->openClosePosition(BinanceEndpointApi::order, $request);
\Kint::dump($res);
```

[here is the screen shown by kint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtaBB.png)

This is two method used in a class binace to make request

```
    /**
     * @param string $signature
     * @return string
     */
    private function getSignature(string $signature)
    {
        return hash_hmac('sha256', $signature, $this->secretKey);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $urlApi
     * @param array $request
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function openClosePosition(string $urlApi,array $request) {
        $request['timestamp'] = time() * 1000;
        $buildQuery = http_build_query($request);
        $signature = $this->getSignature($buildQuery);

        if(!empty($buildQuery)) {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlApi);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $buildQuery . "&signature=" . $signature);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "X-MBX-APIKEY: " . $this->apiKey));
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            return [
                'request' => $buildQuery,
                'response' => $response
            ];
        }else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Binance defines several types of wallets and respective API groups (spot, margin, savings and futures - and maybe some others that I'm not aware of). Your question doesn't show the full request path or how you got the funds info, please check whether you're trying to send the order from the same wallet that your funds are in.

Comment: Tonight I tried to do other tests, and I reloaded the same wallet I used this morning, apparently the refresh is really too slow and therefore even if I transfer funds to the indicated currency, it does not always tell me that the funds are insufficient.

The API to make request is:  https://www.binance.com/api/v3/order

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, I made the same call made yesterday without changing anything, it seems that binance had not immediately updated the status of my wallet.